# how can i add extra rows in dataframe when i execute loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whenever the bid_t of a function increase, I want to add factors to the data frame.
The function I created at the moment is different from what I want because it only returns a data frame once. If determinerank is a function, and this is assumed to work well, how should this function be corrected?
I already change lot of things, but I have no idea to change or add something.
please give me some idea...

```
def determinehamsu(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k):

    encode = LabelEncoder()
    rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [t], 'Now_Rank': [n], 'Amount': [bid_t], 'Weekday': [w], 'Holiday': [h], 'Keyword': [k], 'Target': [rank]},
                      columns=['Time', 'Now_Rank', 'Amount', 'Weekday', 'Holiday', 'Keyword', 'Target'])

    if bid_t <= 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t, 6010,10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            df.append([t, n, bid_t, w, h, k])
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)

    elif bid_t > 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t,0,-10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            df.append([t, n, bid_t, w, h, k])
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.append takes "DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these"
This quote is from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

I think the easier way for you will to be to pass a dict rather than a list. You appends would then look like

```
df = df.append({'Time': t,
                'Now_Rank': n,
                'Amount': bid_t,
                'Weekday': w,
                'Holiday': h,
                'Keyword': k,
                'Target': rank}, ignore_index=True)
```

Edit:
Append returns a new DataFrame so you need to set `df =` to use the new one.

However, if I was written this method, I would probably just create a list of dics and convert them to a DataFrame at the end. But maybe thats just personal choice.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i add your code instead of 'df.append([t, n, bid_t, w, h, k])' this one but it didn't works in function.

Comment: At the risk of descending into a rabbit hole; What happened?

Comment: When a function is executed, rows must be added each time the loop is turned, but only once values are added and no more values are added. I think I fell into a rabbit hole.

Comment: i solved it! the problem is what i didn't return to df! thank you for your help☺️

Comment: Ah ha! Good spot, I'll correct my answer incase anyone has a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You should `append` a pandas DataFrame:

```
def determinehamsu(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k):

    encode = LabelEncoder()
    rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [t], 'Now_Rank': [n], 'Amount': [bid_t], 'Weekday': [w], 'Holiday': [h], 'Keyword': [k], 'Target': [rank]},
                      columns=['Time', 'Now_Rank', 'Amount', 'Weekday', 'Holiday', 'Keyword', 'Target'])

    if bid_t <= 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t, 6010,10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            temp = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [t], 'Now_Rank': [n], 'Amount': [bid_t], 'Weekday': [w], 'Holiday': [h], 'Keyword': [k], 'Target': [rank]})
            df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)

    elif bid_t > 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t,0,-10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            temp = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': [t], 'Now_Rank': [n], 'Amount': [bid_t], 'Weekday': [w], 'Holiday': [h], 'Keyword': [k], 'Target': [rank]})
            df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)
    return df
```